# How to remove application from app listings on Android Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Is there any way to unpublish and then permanently remove an application from the list of applications on Android Developer Console?

Comment: A hack around completely deleting an app from the store is violating one of the rules but this can bring about more consequences.

Comment: The best workaround to remove your application is to migrate or transfer that app to another google play account!!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I wish Google Play would stop giving me warning about things in unpublished apps!

Answer (score 473, accepted):

**No, you can unpublish but once your application has been `live` on the market you cannot delete it**. (Each package name is unique and Google remembers all package names anyway *so you could use this a reminder*)

The "Delete" button only works for unpublished version of your app. Once you published your app or a particular version of it, you cannot delete it from the Market. However, you can still "unpublish" it. The "Delete" button is only handy when you uploaded a new version, then you realized you goofed and want to remove that new version before publishing it.

[A reference](http://www.cynosurex.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Java/Android/Tips_and_Tricks_for_Uploading_Apps_to_Google_Market)

---

Update, 2016

you can now **filter** out unpublished or draft apps from your listing.

[image]

**Unpublish option can be found in the header area, beside PUBLISHED text.**
[image: Unpublish link]

---

**UPDATE**  2020

Due to changes in the new play console, the unpublish option was moved to a different location as follows.
Click `All Apps` in the left pane. Then click the app you want to remove.

Then under the `Setup` option in the left pane, Click `Advanced Settings`.

Then under `App Availablity` on the right, change the status to `UnPublished` and click `Save Changes` at the bottom.

Take a look at the image below:
[image: New UnPublish screenshot]

Comment: sorry but if i unpublish, i can republish one day?

Comment: @Blundell That is quite a bad design - you say there is no way? What if we end up with more than 100 apps on that page when only 5 of them are published...

Comment: I think Google should at least provide a way to hide them from the dashboard... Anyhow, thanks :)

Comment: That is horrible. I uploaded the app, published it and realized that the name in which it is published is wrong, so I had to create a new account, and wanted to upload the same app there. But that I cannot do. So I have to change everything? Thats just lame.

Comment: @Ted: You can change the displayed name of the app if you want to - just not the package name.

Comment: one trick I use is to rename them to something like "Zzzzzxx" so they get sorted to the back.

Comment: Hey @Reuben L., I am facing a problem,I published application and by mistake i uploaded old apk and I have also lost my old keystore file. So console is not accepting new apk with new keystore. Now whether i should unpublish app,and can i publish app again with same name and package or not. What better i could do..?

Comment: @nads: You can publish an app with the same name, but Play remembers package names. Best bet is to unpublish your first app, change the package name of your app, generate a new keystore, and republish under the same name.

Comment: Google should put a hide feature

Comment: Unfortunately i published my apk in production mode but now i unpublished it and i want to publish it in alpha testers. when i tried this then production apk is publishing but not alpha, so how can i publish only alpha test release mode after publishing production apk?Is there any way to hide production apk and to publish alpha testers apk?

Comment: I had published my app with incorrect app name hence I unpublished it.Now I am trying to publish my app with correct app name from different developer console account but I am not allowed to do it.I cannot change the package name of my app.What to do?Please provide suggestions.

Comment: In other words, another move by Google to make you work for them, then  not own your data that you created for them.

Comment: If you still want open beta, but no published release, try this: 
- set you minSdkVersion to as high as possible (currently 25 is accepted by the play store, BUT no devices are compatible :p ). So you end up with an officially published app which will be just a dead entry with no possible installs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39132307/4160084

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `live`? If an APK has only ever been uploaded to the Alpha channel, but never moved to public beta or production, does the same restriction apply?

Comment: If you want to be sure your app is hidden from the store for at least (99% of people), just restrict it for a little country in the world, in the price and availability section.

Comment: Google really needs to add a delete feature because this is in high demand and frankly is getting annoying. I’ve dead app listings sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: Google UI & UX has never been its strong suit hahahah

Comment: I don't understand the difference between deleting and unpublishing. Can users still get to an app that has been unpublished?

Answer (score 171):

Select **Store Presense** then **Pricing Distribution** and select Unpublish from App Availability.
[image]

Google's help for this is here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476#unpublish *(as of Feb-2020)*

Comment: I am unable to click Unpublish button.

Comment: And then how can I delete the app from apps list?

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko once the app published it cannot be deleted from the app list, we can just unpublish it

Comment: See Google Help: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Answer (score 65):

you can remove an App from the store or "Unpublish" by clicking a tiny label bellow your app's title, right side of the "PUBLISHED" green status label.

[image]

Works even if your app was live (published) for long time, mine was.

Regards.

Comment: @swooby - No, this isn't the answer. OP knows how to unpublish the app, he want's to delete it from the list of apps in his developer console, and that is **not** possible.

Comment: This isn't the aswer BUT that is what I was looking for,

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful I did not see that unpublish link, it is not so visible!

Comment: this doesn't seem to be available anymore. See HuyLe's answer.

Comment: That unpublish link no longer exists.  Does anybody know the "new way" to unpublish an app?

Answer (score 59):

[image]

From Google Play Console, Select your app.
Select **Store Presence** and select **Pricing and Distribution** from the side menu.
There is a toggle switch to **Publish** and **Unpublish** app. Select ***UnPublish***  and click **Submit Update** Button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 28):

Actually it is now partially possible: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647

> **Updates to reports**
>
> In late May 2018, you may begin to see changes in
>   your app's metrics based on your users' deletion of data. Some metrics
>   are calculated based on data from users who have agreed to share their
>   data with developers in aggregate.
>
> The metrics that we provide in the Play Console are adjusted to more
>   closely reflect data from all of your users. However, Google will not
>   display data that falls under certain minimum thresholds.
>
> **Delete an app or game**
>
> You can permanently remove draft apps or games
>   from your Play Console. You can also delete:
>
> 1. Published apps or games that haven't been installed on any devices
> 2. Published apps or games that no users are entitled to re-install
>
> In
>   these cases, contact our support team to request that your app's or
>   game's data be permanently deleted.

Comment: The support team replied to my deletion request with more details of the app deletion requirements: 1) App must be in good standing (not rejected, suspended, or otherwise removed). 2) App must have 0 lifetime installs. 3) App must be unpublished for 24 hours (to ensure 0 installs)

Answer (score 20):

**Note:** Adding a new answer as the publish/unpublish option is moved to different location.

As mentioned in other answers you cannot delete the app. With updated Google Play Console (Beta), the **Unpublish** option is moved to different location:

**Setup -> Advanced Settings -> App Availability**

Enable **Published** / **Unpublished** accordingly!

[image]

Comment: Works as of 06/03/2024. Other answers are no longer applicable with the latest UI changes.

Answer (score 9):

The one exception worth noting is that while *you* can't delete apps, the folks over at Google Play Developer Support are able to on their end *if* the app is both unpublished and has 0 lifetime installs. So if your app has 0 lifetime installs, you might be in luck.

First you will need unpublish the app and wait 24 hours (to allow global stats to update and ensure that no last-minute installs happened). Assuming no last-minute installs happen over those 24 hours, you can contact Google Play Developer Support and check to see if they can delete it.

Please note that their requirement for 0 installs is a hard requirement. No exceptions can be made (not even if you installed the app yourself for testing purposes).

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot delete the application once you have published it in Google Play. Google will keep all the apk files. But you can unpublish the version, if you dont want that version to be availaible to user.

Comment: so how can i remove unpublished app

Answer (score 8):

You can't delete the app , but you can unpublish it . By doing so , it won't be available in play store but the user having your application will still be able to use your app .

Steps to follow to un-publish your app : 
To unpublish your app on the Google Play store:

1. Go to https://market.android.com/publish/Home, and log in to your
   Google Play account.
2. Click on the application you want to delete.
3. Click on the Store Presence menu, and click the “Pricing and
   Distribution” item.
4. Click Unpublish

Comment: Thank you!  It didn't occur to me that unpublishing a free app is a sub-category of pricing.  I guess I'll never think like google.

Answer (score 1):

There is strictly no service provided yet from Google Store to delete/remove production app and also you can't change production build for best test.

Answer (score 0):

Once application is made live by publishing it then you can't delete it, although Unpublished apps can be deleted using "Delete app" button as shown :

[image]

Comment: on the screenshot we see that Store Listing and Content Rating are not done yet. This means the app hasn't been published yet. For published apps "Delete" option is unavailable.

Comment: correct, its written above screenshot that "Unpublished apps can be deleted using "Delete app" button"

Comment: "Unpublished" and "Not-yet-published" are very different and the question says, "to unpublish and then permanently remove" which addresses the "was published" not the "not-yet-published" scenario so your answer isn't applicable to the question even though it is correct and could be helpful to someone dealing with a not-yet-published application.

Answer (score 0):

Once app is published once it cannot be deleted from the listing in your console, but rather you can unpublish it only and if you want you can use the filters to hide it from the listing, but the draft apps you can delete them or hide them.