# How to delete the published app from developer console android

Tags: android

I want to remove the published app from play store.So I have unpublished it but it is still present in developer console.How to remove it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't delete app from account. Just make them unpublish. It will be still visible in account ie main server but in playstore it will not be available.

Comment: Please can you provide the steps to unpublish...it would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @bikash_binay [Unpublish App](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) .We can follow the given link to un-publish app successfully. **Hope I can resolve issue after 2019 April**

Answer (score 11):

You can delete an app anytime before it is published.

After it has been published, it "owns" its unique packagename forever in the Google PlayStore app naming hierarchy:

`com.yourdomain.yourapp`

There is no "deleting" this packagename after publication. That would cause mayhem.

Google Analytics, for example needs this permanent unique id. Hostile developers could take over your packagename by forcing you to delete it with bad review attacks.

The package name itself is not really a public-facing asset. If all you want to do is "reboot" your app (ie start again with zero downloads and reviews) then just unpublish (retire) the old packagename and republish the apk under a new packagename.

The right way to publish your app is using the alpha and beta streams in the dev console which do not retain reviews.

The only problem with this is the rule about once an app (package) is priced as free, it remains forever free, meaning you have to republish under a new package name to price a free beta.

Paid betas are only possible if you already have successful apps.

PlayStore publication policies are in constant flux (there is now a manual review policy). You may wish to take your concerns to them directly - they do respond.

I am sure every developer wants to delete and republish an app after finding out that it wont run on device X**, because device X manufacturer has tweaked Android, causing device X owners to give the app unfair reviews.

This is also a way to avoid giving people free upgrades to your apps forever, which is not realistic, esp. given piracy stats. Owners often reboot to start fresh after a major upgrade.

You may want to adopt a packagename with a major version codename baked in, like the big boys do it (mountainlion, xenial, marshmallow, etc)

`com.yourdomain.yourapp.codename`

** X is usually Samsung

Comment: is impossible delete after ?

Comment: After what? Once you hit the publish button, you can only unpublish, not delete the app package. Google does not even delete suspended packages. They remain until the end of days on your list as glowing red sins.

Answer (score 7):

**No, you can unpublish but once your application has been live on the market you cannot delete it**.

(Each `package name is unique` and Google remembers all package names anyway so you could use this a reminder)

The **"Delete"** button only works for unpublished version of your app. Once you published your app or a particular version of it, you cannot delete it from the Market. However, you can still "unpublish" it. The "Delete" button is only handy when you uploaded a new version, then you realized you goofed and want to remove that new version before publishing it.

Comment: Very much like the way MS  abandons major  versions of Windows. It does not delete them, they just stop publishing minor version updates and force you into buying the new major version update. It is still the same product, and everyone knows it.

Answer (score 1):

Select the app from the all application tab then select the particular app which you want to unpublish after selecting the app, You can see the store and pricing tab, Go there and select the option to unpublish and submit the changes from the right upper corner.

Note: We can't delete the app from the developer console but it will be available for users on play store.

Thank you.