# Deleting a published app on Google Play

Tags: android

I recently published an APK and found that it had errors when I went to download it publicly. Unfortuantely, I had named my .keystore `my-release-key.keystore` and since that was the default, I had overwritten this keystore with a new alias name. Now I cannot update my .apk because it is a different .keystore.

I've tried to find an option to delete my APK but cannot find one. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an app from the Play store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519169/how-to-remove-an-app-from-the-play-store)

Comment: The question you provided is that the user did not publish the app. I had mine published thinking it was correct.

Comment: The wording of that question might not be clear, but it is the same situation. See another one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669911/how-to-delete-the-published-app-from-developer-console-android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got your problem, you can 'Unpublish' your app and make it invisible in Play Store but you cannot remove it from the list of apps in your developer console. You'll have to upload your app again with a new package name with it's own keystore, then you can send update to it for sure!

P.S: Keystore passwords, package names are very important and should be saved safely. Prepare an Excell sheet of passwords and package name before developing the app, my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have need change package name of application after that upload new application because you cant  delete once publish app from google play so please do unpublish app and upload new apk file