# How to remove or hide suspended app from google play developer console?

Tags: android, developer-tools, google-developers-console

I got a message from google play developer console:

> Your application has been suspended

How can I remove or hide [the app] from developer console? 
And can anybody explain the message:

> Google has been notified that aspects of your app, App Name, allegedly infringe upon the trademarks of others, and it has been removed from Google Play due to a violation of the Developer Program Policies.

Advance thanks....

Comment: You can't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519169/how-to-remove-an-app-from-the-play-store

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/chromium-apps/Orx2vQD-PSk

Answer (score 2):

It appears you cannot remove the app from your developer console. Even if you "Unpublish" the app it seems to still appear and will continue to negatively effect your account. You can however fix the app and submit an appeal using the link here:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2993242?rd=1

Also, the message provided by Google:

> Google has been notified that aspects of your app, App Name, allegedly
>   infringe upon the trademarks of others, and it has been removed from
>   Google Play due to a violation of the Developer Program Policies.

is flagging your application name for being too similar to another application. If possible you should try renaming your application.

Comment: In my research I found the following article, but keep in mind I have no affiliation or background in this type of development:  https://andrewrezk.com/how-i-restored-my-app-on-google-play-after-suspension/