# Removing .apk from Google Play or Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, apk

So I made this test application and uploaded it to developer console, but because it was my first application it's package is named com.myfirstapp.program. now later I have made much better version of the same program and this time it is under proper package name, however google play wont let me upload my new program because package name is different. And I really dont want to use com.myfirstapp.program. Is there anything I can do? I tried searching if I could delete my apk entirely but found out it is impossible, so I am kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer about unpublishing and deleting from Google Play.

[How remove application from app listings on Android Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console)

Comment: so what do I do now? I have to go with com.myfirstapp. package name?

Comment: If you want the app to update in the market, it must stay the same.  Otherwise, you'll have to start over with the new package name.

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to remove an uploaded .apk from play.google.com - is there a way?

Comment: @Jonny: no, there's no way it seems... sadly.