# How can I publish my app in Alpha test mode only?

Tags: console, google-play, apk, alpha, production

I've been searching online but I still haven't found the answer to this..

On the Google Play Developer Console, I uploaded an APK file to the 'Production' tab. I now want to test the app in 'Alpha' mode first. How can I test the app in 'Alpha' without publishing the Production APK at the same time?

I've already published then unpublished the 'Production' version, so it seems I can't delete the app from the console and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [publish section](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) click on your app, click on "APK", then click "Alpha Testing" then upload now new APK.

Does this work?

I have App in production and can upload alpha/beta apks...

Edit:

taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836873/google-play-beta-testing-without-a-published-app#17096134):

click on "Advanced Mode" 
click on "Production" -> Deactivate APK

then proceed as mentioned above

Comment: I can upload alpha/beta apks in addition to the Production apk, but if I click on 'Republish App' at the top-right of the screen, would it not publish the 'Production' version too?

Comment: I guess you should check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836873/google-play-beta-testing-without-a-published-app#17096134)