# How to publish a production app without testing in google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my apps in google play store **as quick as** I can.
How I can publish my apps on google play store without testing.
I have an `.aab` bundle I uploaded it and all requirements are fulfilled.
I am new I this field I tried lot to publish my app without testing but I can't.
How I can publish an app without testing step by step for beginner friendly?

I just want my app in play store so I can see my apps in play store

I already read: [Google Play Beta testing without a published app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836873/google-play-beta-testing-without-a-published-app)

Some resources for better understanding:

[image: Google play console]

Thanks!

Comment: internal app sharing ?

Comment: Is your aab signed?

Comment: I uploaded `.aab` file Is `aab` signed is a different process.

Comment: Where and how can I signed my app?

Comment: @a_local_nobody "internal app sharing ?" mean

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to Production (left navigation) -> Create new release (button at the top right).

Some screenshots for reference:

[image]
[image]