# Delete unpublished apk from Google Play is not possible

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I have a very stupid problem. We created an application in Google Play, filled with all required information - translations, screenshots, etc.

Now for testing reasons, we uploaded the first .apk with a different package name (another already existent app).

The question: How can I delete this .apk!?

It seems not to be possible! I only find an option to delete the application, but I guess that this will delete the whole thing, the descriptions, screenshots, etc.

When I try to upload .apk with the correct package name, it says, I can't, because the package name has to be the same.

Thanks

Comment: Upload the correct apk with the new package name as a new application. Then transfer over the old information from the old application by cut and pasting from one window to the other.

Comment: Maybe this answer is what you are looking for: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Comment: @Kuikiker this is just about an unpublished apk  - I don't want to remove the application, just to change this file!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk the problem is I don't have the screenshots and the other images, other team did this, and I don't see a way to download them from Google Play again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read more carefully in future.

> Please note that package names for app files are unique and permanent,
>   so please choose wisely. Package names cannot be deleted or re-used in
>   the future. Keep in mind that if you've lost your keystore, you'll
>   have to publish the app with a new package name and a new key. You
>   should also update the description of the original app and unpublish
>   it.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Comment: But how am I supposed to know that it will select the package name when I upload (not even publish) the first .apk... and that it will not de-select it if I remove this unpublished .apk... doesn't make sense necessarily.

Comment: It takes about 20-30 minutes to upload files for multilanguges projects. I think this is very negligible problem to recreate the new app.

Comment: I'll do it. I just thought there was a better way. The problem I have is that I don't have the images (featured, big icon, screenshots), and  the app has to be published today, and the team which has it is not anymore available today. And it seems not to be possible to download them from Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

You can Only Unpublish your applications which will make it invisible to the people on google play but it will be still visible to you in the developer console