# Remove application from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I put an app on Google Play Store, and now want to remove the app from the list of all applications, does anyone know how to remove?

Comment: There is a thread here that might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Answer (score 0):

Open App in your publisher account and click Button "Unpublish this app".

Answer (score 0):

Under the developer console where you click to publish the app, if it is already published it becomes unpublished.

Click this and confirm you are sure then your app will no longer appear in the play store (may take a couple of hours for changes to propogate).

It will still however be shown in your developer console, you can't unfortunately remove it from there but people definitely won't be able to download from the store.