# Removing in-app billing application from Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

My app always checks on start whether it contains a purchased product or not via In-app Billing interface (`inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PRO_VERSION)`) and thus adapts its functionality.

Does anyone have an idea what will happen if an In-app Billing application is removed from Google Play store after end users downloaded it and bought its In-app product?

What will the above function call return in this case? Can a user still use the product or does Google Play server return `null`?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console According to my knowledge google play will allow only that user to access purchased product after deleting it but they will not allow content for the new users.