# How to remove the apk file in google play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-account

I am new to android and I have released my first app in Google play by using the account .I have entered all the details correctly but uploaded old apk file now I want to remove that apk file and upload new apk file .I can not see any option like delete apk file ?

Could someone tell me how to remove that apk and upload new one?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Answer (score 0):

**Open Developer Console >> All Applications >> Select App >> Top Right >> Select Unpublish this app**

Comment: unpublish is moved to top mid location as of 2015/03/12

Comment: top mid in gray color (mostly in APK section)

Answer (score -1):

I believe once you upload new apk file the old one gets replaced.

(That what I did last time I published and replaced with a new one..)

You can go to Google Developer Console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish),

click the app you wish to change. Then on the left side, click APK.

In APK section, you can simply upload a new APK to production.