# How to remove Rejected Apps from Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

It was my first try to uploading my first android game in GooglePlay Store. My App got rejected two times because of some error later I fixed it, and uploaded it successfully. Now I want to remove those Rejected apps form the list because it has the name as I wanted to put on my app that has been uploaded successfully.
Please Help thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Open the developer panel in your browser and look for the following code

```
<div class="ABL6ESB-Gf-i"> 
<span class="ABL6ESB-Gf-h">
  <span style="color:#777;">Unpublished</span>
</span> 
<span aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span> 
<a class="gwt-Anchor" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" href="javascript:">Unpublish app</a> 
<a class="gwt-Anchor" aria-hidden="true" style="display: delete;" href="javascript:">Delete app</a>
```

Replace `display: none;` by `display: block;` for **Unpublish app**, then click it in your browser.
  After few hours (unpublish delay) you should be able to delete the app.

  That's the beauty of client side business logic.

Comment: I got: An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (668269003)

Answer (score 0):

If your app has been published then it is not possible to remove it from the list of applications associated with your developer account. It is possible to hide the entry, but that will not help your situation.

Take a look at this thread for a discussion on this issue: [How remove application from app listings on Android Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console)

Comment: I found a solution just now,  Its a bug in developer console maybe. If u click on All Application then Select your App go to statistics there will be Unpublished app button for just 1 sec, you have to click it once u see, when the page loads completely, Unpublished app button will be removed. It only shows when page is loading.

Comment: This does not apply to rejected apps, as the unpublish button is not displayed.