# Google play, I accidentally uploaded production APK, now can't do beta testing

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I first accidentally uploaded an APK to production in the google play developer console. Now when I click publish, it actually publishes my app to the play store, even though I have now uploaded to the alpha channel. there is no way to delete the production APK. I hope I don't need to delete the whole app project from google play?

Comment: *I hope I don't need to delete the whole app project from google play?* you cannot do that anyway

Comment: true. So Im totally screwed. This seems to be a flaw in their publishing flow. If you accidentally publish in production, you can no longer publish to a testing channel

Comment: You better contact google support. There is only so much we can tell you here.

Comment: why this question was downscored???

Comment: Google is terrible for allowing this to happen so easily. You would think they would warn that you are doing something that cannot be undone.

Comment: Made the same mistake -- now waiting (2 days?) for Google Support to delete the accidentally promoted release. This is ridiculous. They need a "Delete Release" button for unpublished apps.

Comment: Happened to me too.... this is ridiculous this company makes billions and can't add a damn delete release button or allow us to really decide more of what needs to be done.

Answer (score 28):

I contacted google play support. And yes, if you accidentally upload to production, you can no longer test. This was their response:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play about removing a published Production APK.
>
> We don't currently support the functionality you're requesting. In this case, you would need to unpublish the current app and then publish a new app with a new package name. I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.
>
> We currently require that once a Production APK has been published, the app must always have an APK in Production. This requirement is in place so that we are in compliance with the DDA by ensuring that once an app has been made publicly available, that it remains available for any users who may have installed it.
>   However, we can delete an app in certain circumstance when an app has been unpublished for more than 24 hours and no install was detected.
>
> As you have already unpublished your app, there is nothing you can do more from your side. Instead, we will wait for another 24 hours to see whether the app has any installs. If there is no installs, I will proceed with app deletion and get back to you after 24 hours. Then, you will be able to upload the same package in Beta track.
>
> Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Update from 2019. I have the same issue by accident and received a similar response from the Google Play team unfortunately.

Comment: FYI, your app must have 0 installs. Even if it was installed through an Internal or Alpha track and that install was by yourself, they will not delete the app for you.

Comment: I'm going through the same thing. They really need to differentiate alpha/beta testing and publishing. I just emailed Google Play team and it says that they usually take 2 business days to get back to me.

Answer (score 22):

I have an improvement on top of goodKode's answer. On this date (Oct 2016) there is no `minSdkVersion` that Play Store would accept and would yield 0 compatible devices - 26 is not allowed and 25 was released in August.

There are other limiting fields in AndroidManifest that can be used to the same effect. I picked `<uses-library android:name="some.bogus.feature.that.doesnt.exist" android:required="true"/>` and when uploading the APK to production, Play Store reports happily that 0 devices are supported but allows the upload. Result: the app cannot be found via search but is accessible with the beta link.

A full list of filters can be found here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: Using this approach will any user be able to find the app in the play store? Even if they will be not allowed to download an APK.

Comment: Has something changed? How does it not work anymore? @b005t3r

Comment: For me it works but when users click the invitation link they are presented with the play store version which is not compatible with their (or any) device. How can this be overcome?

Comment: the user needs to be a beta tester, and you need to upload a beta apk without the `uses-library` attribute @MaximilianKörner

Comment: That was exactly what I did. Anyway Google support deleted the app for me as I had 0 downloads so far. If this is the case I highly recommend this over hacky solutions

Answer (score 18):

I found a neat trick as I encountered the same situation and had to find a satisfactory solution...

***Update and general solution***: set a flag (feature) that is not supported on any device! DonSteep recommends the <uses-library> flag.

This will keep the app "published" but in practice, no device will see it.

Good luck!

---

*Old answer (outdated):*

1) upload a new production release with `minSdkVersion [apilevel]` in your build.gradle where "apilevel" is as high as the Google Play Store allows - currently 25 while the highest released platform level is 24 / Nougat. This means that your app will be still officially published, but wont show up in searches as none of the devices will be compatible.
As of today (Aug 2015), this will do: `minSdkVersion 25`

2) enjoy open beta!

Comment: This was a great find, but as of today cannot be applied because version 25 is already released and store will not accept the number 26. Alternative in my answer.

Comment: But will it still be available for testers if the version is considered "broken" by the store?