# How to keep only Alpha version on Play store

Tags: android, testing, alpha

My android app is live on Google Play. The latest version is 22. I had not used alpha and beta testing so far. Now App Owner said that Unpublish app from app store So that nobody that can view app any platform PC, mobile etc.

He said only selective people can view this app. So I decided Alpha testing using Google plus community. But problem is that if I unpublish app, Link of Alpha testing is not showing the app in play store for newly added users in the community even they become the tester. It's only working Users who have downloaded the app. If I republish app then it is working for ALL.

So my main question is How does Alpha testing possible for new users of google plus community without publishing App?

Comment: I got the answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722321/google-play-i-accidentally-uploaded-production-apk-now-cant-do-beta-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the Publish documentation carefully, you will find that the version code of Alpha should always be greater than beta, and beta version code should always be greater than production.

i.e

> alphaVC > betaVC > productionVC

the alpha version always remains higher, you cannot put a lower version apk.

The flow of testing is, fist rollout in alpha, then move same out to beta and then same one to production, on passing of consequent tests and approvals.

Comment: Thanks for reply  if I upload new version with alpha testing lets say 23 then production apk(version 22) will see on google play

Comment: Yes, the alpha and beta is for only the people who opt for it, You can put a custom tester list using various methods, best preffered is a google account. Also google apps for work domain account users. that is available in the console.

Comment: please approve the answer if u could

Comment: don't worry about approval but i want to disbale production apk permananetly. I want only Alpha testing should visible on play store. How i disbale production apk?

Comment: u can simply unpublish it. it will no longer be available for production.

Comment: But problem is that if I unpublish app, Link of Alpha testing is not showing the app in play store for newly added users in the community even they become the tester. It's only working Users who have downloaded the app. If I republish app then it is working for ALL.

Comment: OK if u already have an full roll out then ill recommend u to delete the listing and recreate new one with only alpha. as i explained the flow, it will have that issue