# Android unpublish the published apk

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an apk in play store in the morning and it's live now but i saw a crash in the same apk. I have fixed the bug and rolled out a new version but it will take time to be shown in play store.

I don't want anyone to download the previous version which already is live and crashing. How can I unpublish that?

Comment: https://ibb.co/MGPrz23

Comment: may solutions from here will usefull for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722321/google-play-i-accidentally-uploaded-production-apk-now-cant-do-beta-testing

Comment: @Nik that's not the solution man. I just want to deactivate a particular apk which is already live.

Comment: @NileshPanchal i don't think that's the solution. I just want to deactivate one apk so that no more people download that. My new version anyhow will be available in some time.

Comment: @ShubhamAnand is this your first apk that is available in play store?

Comment: @Nik no. I already have some more.

Comment: you can retain your previous version of apk

Comment: This experiment seems risky to me. Have you tried this before?

Comment: Retained APKs can only be deactivated, if you have newer update for roll-out to your previous release.

Comment: please have a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the Google Play store Console here is the procedure of unpublishing your app.

1. Go to your "play.google.com" dashboard.
2. Select your app
3. In left menu item select "Store presence"
4. Then, select "Pricing & distribution"
5. Click "Unpublish" in the "App Availability" section

when you want to publish a new version follow the above step and in the last step select option "publish" your application is live with the latest version.

Comment: I dont have to remove the app from play store, just deactivate an apk which is live.

Comment: when you unpublish the app it means your application not visible in the play store. when you change option unpublish to publish your application live again.

Comment: Don't want that to happen man. I already have uploaded the new apk 3 hours back. I hope it goes live in another one hour.

Comment: The new app will be live max to max 3 to 4 hours. Also, I'm facing this type of issue much time.