# Is there any way to delete rejected app from Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-developers-console

Is there any way to delete rejected app from Google Play Developer Console?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot3e1.png)

Comment: I guess you will get an email why they rejected it. So you just need to update app with their criteria and upload another one and it will be fine.

Comment: Hope this will help [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Answer (score 4):

you cannot delete rejected/suspended/live apps from developer console. Either you can update the app again by looking at the email that why it was rejected at first place or you can hide them by unchecking rejected apps from filter on console.

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete the drafted App but you cant delete rejected or live app.

> Well, the answer is that the strategy still works. If you've never published the app, you can remove all traces of it from Google Play and another publisher account can then upload an app with the same package name. All you need to do is deactivate (if necessary) and then delete all .apk files and the app will disappear from your developer console.If the app was ever published, this will not work. You can unpublish an app, but you cannot delete any .apk files that were ever active while the app was published.