# How to update a deleted app in the google play console

Tags: android, google-play

I sumbitted an app on the google play console, and it was removed since it didn't respect the google play policy. I can see the status of my app is "Deleted". I made a new version and uploaded it in the release manager. Is there a specific thing to re-submit the app. Because even after adding a new apk and launching it in production, the status of my app is still "Deleted". Thank you in advance for your responses

Comment: then delete the app completed first then create a new app there and upload apk there

Comment: You mean I have to create a new app with a new bundle ?

Comment: yes , try that , Delete app from console completely and then add a new app there

Comment: How can I completely delete an app ?

Comment: AFAIK you can only Unpublish but not delete an app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Comment: try looking at any better solution , if none works for u , Then just create a   new app with different package and create a new app on console and upload apk there :)