# Delete app from play console

Tags: android, console, google-play, app-store, console-application

how to delete app from play console?
Is there any way to delete rejected app from Google Play Developer Console?
How we can permanently remove draft apps or games from Play Console.

Comment: you may find an answer already exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How remove application from app listings on Android Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot delete your app from Google Play. Instead, you can unpublish an app and it will no longer appear in the store.

Go to the Play Store console for your app, click `Setup`, `Advanced settings`, then switch `App availability` to `Unpublished`.

Comment: I wish I could delete the old apps or at least hide them from my view. When I see some of them it triggers me.

Comment: @spartygw, I understand your pain. Even I get triggered by some apps that were failed.

Answer (score 3):

It baffles me why Google won't make it easy for developers to remove or unpublish an app from the dashboard.
To unpublish your app:

1. Go to your Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Select Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
4. In the 'App Availability' section, select **Unpublish**.

When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find and download on Google Play.