# How to clear the removed application from app listings on Android Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My apps are removed by Google Play, I hope to delete or hidden them from my app listings, how can I do? Thanks!

BTW, I can't unpublish the removed app from google play.

And more, I have read the article [How to remove application from app listings on Android Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-to-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console)

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you can unpublish but once your application has been live on the market you cannot delete** it. (Each package name is unique and Google remembers all package names anyway so you could use this a reminder)

The "Delete" button only works for unpublished version of your app. Once you published your app or a particular version of it, you cannot delete it from the Market. However, you can still "unpublish" it. The "Delete" button is only handy when you uploaded a new version, then you realized you goofed and want to remove that new version before publishing it.

**and after the [update](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647) on may 2018 :**

> **Delete an application or a game**
>
> You can permanently delete your draft apps or games from the Play
>   console. You can also delete:
>
> published applications or games that have not been installed on any
>   device.
>
> published applications or games that no user has the right to
>   reinstall.
>
> In this case, contact our support team to request the final deletion
>   of your app or game data.

Comment: I hope to delete or hidden these removed apps  from my app listings in Image 1, how can I do? Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately you can't , even hiding it seems to be impossible ! the only hope is as i mentioned in the answer , is to contact support team

Comment: please consider my answer :)

Comment: this is such a pain in the ass google. As an Indie dev I'm happy to let a huge swarm of projects die off naturally, but the play console doesn't even let me sort or filter these out.