# Deleting (NOT Unpublishing) Android App From Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I've been working on my first app but haven't yet submitted it for review on the Play Console, only internal testing. Long story short, I trashed my project folder that had been configured with signing keys and am now trying to re-upload my app (recovered via Git) to the Play Console. I resigned it with new keys and as expected this prevents me from uploading my current app as a newer version of the original (now trashed) app. If I try to submit my app as a new app I receive an error:

```
You need to use a different package name because "com.example.app" is already used by one of your other applications.
```

I have a strong preference to keep this package name. Is there any way to delete the existing draft app? The only workaround I have found so far would be to create a new Google account and start fresh. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled "delete app google play console".
This led me to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-to-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console) that had [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50947275/1197251) which points to [this help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647) that says:

> Delete an app or game
>
> You can permanently remove draft apps or games from Play Console. You can also delete:
>
> ```
> Published apps or games that haven't been installed on any devices 
>
> Published apps or games that no users are entitled to re-install
> ```
>
> In these cases, contact our support team to request that your app's or game's data be permanently deleted.

Where "contact our support team" lead to [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing).