# How to delete UNREVIEWED app from play console?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

How to remove UNREVIEWED app from play console. 
I recently forgot my keystore password and due to it, I am not able to build and update it. 
So I was looking for deleting the app in the play console. I was starting with internal test there but actually it is not reviewed therefore not tested by anyone being unpublished. 
But I could not find any option to delete the app.

**Dashboard**
[image]
[image]
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**NOT REVIEWED, NOT TESTED, NOT PUBLISHED**

**HOW TO DELETE IT ?**

[image]

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

[image]

Comment: you can only delete an app which was never published before. unpublished apps cannot be deleted - refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-to-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Comment: But mine too is unpublished as you can see it is inactive in production ..

Comment: Why not ask google?

Comment: yeah, Thanks to google, they did helped.

Comment: @supernatural how did they resolve things? Did they have to delete it on their side or did they give you steps to delete it yourself?

Comment: They did it on there side, i mailed a request @monstermac77

Comment: Just emailed them. Thanks!

Comment: I"ve had so many back and forths with them and they just say they can't delete it because there's still install statistics but we have no idea what phone it would have been installed on. Pretty annoying. Would love to know if anyone managed to figure out a way to get the statistics wiped and/or convince Google to remove it.